# PubSubHubBub in the .net platform

Tags: .net, publish-subscribe

PubSubHubBub is a simple, server-to-server webhook-based pubsub (publish/subscribe) protocol for any web accessible resources. It is developed by Google in Python.

Does anybody know any implementation of similar solution developed in .NET?

I know that I can use PubSubHubBub with .NET as well. I'm just looking for a .NET solution because I work for a .NET/Microsoft oriented company.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you do not want to use BizTalk because id does "to much".

I guess you do not want [Nservicebus](http://particular.net/nservicebus) because it costs money.

I guess you do not want to use an open source solution like this [PubSub](https://pubsub.codeplex.com/) because "no support".

So if all above is right then I would say: Build it yourself following [this path](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2008/05/17/building-a-pub-sub-message-bus-with-wcf-and-msmq.aspx). (Possibly using more modern rest/api services.)

Cheers.